# How to deploy PWA on android built using preact.js?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, progressive-web-apps, preact

Can PWA(Progressive Web App) built using Preact.js be deployed as an android application (.apk) on android ?? Like apps like Uber Lite. and Other Go Apps on Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can deploy it using [pwa-builder](https://www.pwabuilder.com)

But it has some disadvantage : you need to have basic knowledge of android studio and gradle.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing PWAs (Progressive Web Apps) with native Android applications. (.apk) They are two different things. You can't make a PWA and deploy it as an Android .apk application. A [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) is basically a web-site that can be cached locally on the browser and given a bookmark on the home screen. So you are asking about two different things:

#### 1. An Android App with Preact

If you wanted to make a native Android application (.apk) using Preact.js you could make a web site with Preact and bundle it into a [Cordova app](https://cordova.apache.org/). See the [Android Platform Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/). This doesn't seem like a bad idea as it appears to have [pretty good performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scOgFibPgPY)

#### 2. A PWA with Preact

[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) is a very popular starter-kit and fantasticly easy way to get a PWA up and running with React with just a couple of commands. To use this with *Preact* you can:

- Use this fork: [Create Preact App](https://github.com/just-boris/create-preact-app)
- Follow [Daniel Spitzer]'s [5 simple steps to adapt create-react-app to use Preact](https://github.com/sampi/create-react-app-hack). (See also [his brief talk explaining this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAxJCo3ZZ2w))

**I would recommend option number #2** (A PWA with React) as there would be no performance advantages for #1, and PWA's are quite awesome in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Preact, but based on what I've read it is a minimalistic alternative to ReactJS, and does not have native capabilities. Uber used it for their mobile website, not for their native application. If you want to make Android apps using React you will have to use React Native. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

Comment: I am familiar with react-native but what about its go application which is a PWA?

Comment: PWAs aren't native apps so they wouldn't be downloadable from the Play Store, PWAs are websites optimized to perform similar to native apps (loading without internet connection, ability to add to your homescreen) https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/